# ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream with sockets

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I'm making an online game using ObjectOutputStream... to exchange data. Since I have different types of data I'm using the write/readObject() functions only. I was wondering if sending a String for commands was good practice or if there is a better, safer solution.

When I say I send commands with a String, for example I have a chat and I want to ignore a user, so I send to the server "block +username"; if I want to add a friend I send "addfriend +username", etc.

Comment: Should be OK, just be careful that someone doesn't inject invalid bytes into a string (causing a decoder to crash), or somehow spoof a command they shouldn't be able to issue.  Program very defensively, in other words.  But given you seem to basically be doing "chat commands" I'd probably use a String too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using serialized objects might create lot of interoperability work if you are going for a serious installation. It also can become a bottleneck. I would (besides the obvious of using any other messeging protocol) stick to DataOutputStream if you look for a compact home grown protocol.

Sending strings as serialized java objects is the most suprising thing to do (and wont easily allow you to have client or servers in different languages).

If you want to be cool, use JSON and Websocket. :)